# LaTeX tokenizing

Tags: math-mode, macros

With LaTeX macro

```
\newcommand{\CH}[2]{#1\choose#2}
```

and input

```
\CH63=20
```

my hope was to get the equivalent of

```
{6\choose3}=20
```

but I get

```
{6\choose3=20}
```

instead.

I know how to fix the text to get what I want, but I really want to change the macro.
Any ideas? And if you know, where did you find it, since I spent a considerable time to find an online answer and would like to have access to a document that can provide answers to questions like this one.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: In terms of documentation, you are using a _plain TeX_ command here with _LaTeX_: you are 'on your own' in many ways (you have to know what you are doing by, for example, reading _The TeXbook_). The answer covers things in the specific case, but more generally the braces used to set up a `\newcommand` don't 'count' for grouping around a construct like `\choose`, hence needing a second set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `\newcommand{\CH}[2]{{#1 \choose #2}}`. The second set of parenthesis will keep the choose command self contained.  Alternatively, your could use: `\newcommand{\CH}[2]{\binom{#1}{#2}}`. Or, frankly, why not just use `\binom`?

Comment: `\let\CH=\binom` :)